# Strange Javascript addition in Email address

Tags: email, gmail, javascript, email-client

recently I received an email from someone whose email address contained strange additions.

Instead of `Somebody <address@gmail.com>`, it was `Somebody <address@gmail.com<javascript:_e(%7B%7D,'cvml','address@gmail.com');>`

What is the added part's function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [a post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662296/javascript-cvml-in-an-email-address), it seems that it is the Javascript to generate custom font.  `%7B%7D` translates to `{}` and "`cvml` returns `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml` which is an XML namespace for Vector Markup Language".